# Automatic run of VSTS web tests daily

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2008, tfsbuild

Please I want a way to make daily schedule to run a set of VSTS 2008 web tests automatically over night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing automated daily builds with some type of continual integration setup, you would add the tests as part of your build.

If you need to simply run the tests outside of any other environment, there is a great, open-source job scheduling API called Quartz.  It can be found at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/.